# Script to prompt user to select / input IP address

Tags: shell-script, rhel, network-interface

I would like to know if my script below is able to achieve the following in a logical manner:

1. Ask the user whether the machine's existing IP address (if any) is correct.
   It needs to list out the existing addresses, allowing the user to select.e.g.

   `eth0 127.0.0.1
   eth1 168.21.51.23 etc`
2. Should the user reject the option 1, ask the user to provide the IP address to be assigned.
3. Else, if the user rejects the existing IP addresses or did not give any input, the script will input a predefined default IP address  e.g. 192.168.81.23 to the system.

Do note that the following script will be part of a larger program I am trying to create. I have tried using the following script for abovementioned requirements but with some syntax errors:

---

```
#!/bin/bash
getinfo
echo "Obtain the static IP address"
read -p "Is it an Existing address/User input/NIL? (E/U/N)" interface
echo ""
 case $interface in 
       [Ee]* ) exist_addr ;;
       [Uu]* ) user_supply ;;
       [Nn]* ) default;;
           * ) echo "Please enter Existing, User or Nil!" ;;
 esac
} 

exist_addr()
{
   #calling earlier script for listing existing interfaces
./get_addr
read -p "Confirm the existing address settings correct? (y/n)" reply
case $reply in 
      [Yy]* ) ./scriptfornextstepoftheprogram ;;
      [Nn]* ) getinfo ;;
          * ) echo "Please enter Yes or No!" ;;
esac
}

user_supply()
{
read -p "Enter the IP address for the network interface" supplied_IP
echo ""
       read -p "Is the IP address entered correct? (y/n)" yn
       case $yn in
             #when yes I input the ip address to the interface 
          [Yy]* ) ip address add $supplied_IP dev eth1 ;;
          [Nn]* ) getinfo ;;
              * ) echo "Please enter Yes or No!" ;;
       esac
}

default()
{ read -p "Enter he default predefined IP address" default_IP
  echo ""
        read -P "Is this the predefined IP address? (y/n)" yn
        case $yn in
            [Yy]* ) ip address add $default_IP dev enp0s3 ;;
            [Nn]* ) getinfo ;;
                * ) echo "Please enter Yes or No!" ;;
         esac
}
exit 1
```

Does the script achieve the goal correctly?

Comment: Would like to clarify for my question:  is it better to use nested if or case statements are good enough and whether my code is organised appropriately.

Comment: What are the syntax errors?

Comment: I have made some attempts to correct. Current Error found:    line 3: getinfo: command not found.

Comment: **There is no question here.**

Comment: Have rephrased my title and contents.

Comment: There is still no question here.  And by the way, the statement *"I would like to know if my script below is able to achieve the following in a logical manner"* is already answered by *"I have tried using the following script for abovementioned requirements but with some syntax errors,"* i.e. the answer is "No, it is not able to do that."  You aren't including the precise syntax error, either.  **Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and apply it to this question.**

Comment: @Wildcard **There is question here.** Although the question would match the profil of the https://codereview.stackexchange.com much better.

Comment: @peterh, no—to post there you need working code.  Broken code is explicitly off-topic.

Comment: @Wildcard Well, it is right. First the OP should try the script, explain why it doesn't work and asking it as a debug question. Furthermore, the indentation is a crap. My opinion is that posting not indented code nears intentional destructivity. All these all true. But there is a question in this post, even if it is not written clearly, and the question is: "Is this script o.k.?" My edit made it only more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to know if my script below is able to achieve the following in a logical manner

No. It is missing a referenced command or function used in its first statement, and has a syntax error that will cause it to fail immediately after the first question. You can see this by pasting your code into https://shellcheck.net/ or by attempting to run the code.

> Does the script achieve the goal correctly?

This is the same question as at the beginning, and the answer is still no.

Comment: thanks for directing me to this site! Will try to edit based on the errors highlighted.

Comment: eventually the following thread helped me solve the syntax error problem  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895946/syntax-error-near-unexpected-token-bash